# Default RequireJS Context Config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two modules:

**module1.js**:

```
define([], function () {
    var self = {};

    self.name = function () {
        return 'module1';
    };

    return self;
});
```

**module2.js:**

```
define([], function () {
    var self = {};

    self.name = function () {
        return 'module2';
    };

    return self;
});
```

And **index.html** page is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.10/minified/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var require1 = require.config({
            context: 'context1',
            baseUrl: '.',
            paths: {
                'mod': 'module1'
            }
        });

        var require2 = require.config({
            context: 'context2',
            baseUrl: '.',
            paths: {
                'mod': 'module2'
            }
        });

        require1(['mod'], function (module) {
            console.log('require1 : ' + module.name());
        });

        require2(['mod'], function (module) {
            console.log('require2 : ' + module.name());
        });

        require(['mod'], function (module) {
            console.log('require : ' + module.name());
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I specify which config will be used by default for last call:

```
    require(['mod'], function (module) {
        console.log('require : ' + module.name());
    });
```

Also if you know some intersting article about requireJS context it will be great if you share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last call will use the default/global context. In your case, you haven't setup any config for this context, so it'll use default values.

To add a config to the default context, simply do so using `require.config()` **without** specifying a `context` name.